# Forgot the username

Tags: fedora, authentication

I have fedora installed in my system. I know the password but i forgot the user name. I can access through terminal but i don't no how to login through gui. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

With `cat /etc/passwd` you can see all the users on the system. With `id` you can see what your current user/group is.

Comment: No, `/etc/passwd` may well not contain the account, and may not be used at all on some systems.

Comment: Unless the user is using network authentication exclusively, the /etc/passwd file will show all local users in Fedora.

Comment: @bignose: true enough. My answer is not valid for all unix/linux systems and depends on the rest of your config. But with a normal fresh install of fedora, it usually holds ;)

Comment: @TuxRug: indeed, but I wouldn't expect that from an out-of-the-box fedora install

Answer (score 2):

Use `getent passwd` to see all **accounts that exist** on the host.

Use `who` to see which accounts are **currently logged in** to a terminal on the host.

Use `id` to see which account **owns the current shell** process.

Comment: I did not know about the getent and id commands.  I'll have to try them next time I'm on my linux system.